# Route segment without matching controller or action in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, router

Take a look at this route:

```
{controller}/{currency=USD}/{action=view}
```

It matches URLs of type `rates/GBP/edit` (and others as well..). `Rates` map to `controller` and `edit` maps to `view`. Thats fine. What I don't understand is to what the middle segment `GBP` is matched to.

If it would be the other way around => `{controller}/{action=view}/{currency=USD}`, GPB would be a parameter to action method. But with current syntax, it looks like a parameter for controller which doesn't make sense.

Example route config:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>{
        routes.MapRoute(
                name:"def",
                template:"{controller}/{currency=USD}/{action=view}"
        );
    });
```

Example controller:

```
public class RatesController : Controller{
   public IActionResult Edit(){
       return View();
   }
}
```

So, to what code is `currency` matched, if any? Perhaps the same question.. how can I access the currency segment value?

Comment: Have you added that route to the startup config?

Comment: Just by using conventional approach. Added additional example